# How to group array element to a new group array?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of lines:

```
   this.lines = [
    0: {indexLine: 0, group: 16, columns: [,…]}
    1: {indexLine: 1, group: 16,…}
    2: {indexLine: 2, group: 16,…}
    3: {indexLine: 3, group: 9,…}
    ]
```

I want to group lines by group to be able render it in different tables.

I have tried this:

```
 let arr: any = {};
        this.lines.forEach((line) => {
          if (!arr[line.group]) {
            arr[line.group] = [];
          }

          arr[line.group].push(line);
        });
```

Comment: Do they all have the same fields, like do all lines have a columns field?

Comment: why don't you give your desired result array?

Comment: Your code seems like it should work. What is not working exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to get what you want:

```
const result = this.lines.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.group]) {
    acc[item.group] = [];
  }
  acc[item.group].push(item);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

If you want to get all the groups as multiple arrays instead of an object, you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to do just that:

```
const groups = Object.values(result);
```

Comment: I get this error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'group')`. Despite each element in lines has group

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I made some edits. The `acc` variable needs to be returned from the callback.

Comment: And this gives me `console.log(response.lines.length);` 4 elements. so why I get undefined `item` inside reduce?

Comment: If you use foreach I get item inside.

Comment: I mentioned before, you need to check the answer again, as I made some edits to it. The first variant did not return anything from the callback, and by the nature of the `reduce` method, the return value of the callback will be used in subsequent calls, hence the `undefined`. Now it should behave as intended, please check the updated answer again (refresh this whole page if necessary).

Comment: It should be `response.lines.reduce((acc, item, index, array) => {}` it fixed my prev issue. Also I get error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '16')` on `acc[item.group]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Set` to get unique `group` values from array of object. `new Set(lines.map(x => x.group)` will give you array of unique values of group.

Convert that set to array with `Array.from()`.

Now you can use map to iterate through unique group values and `Array.filter` would give you all matching elements.

---

```js
let lines = [
    {indexLine: 0, group: 16},
    {indexLine: 1, group: 16},
    {indexLine: 2, group: 16},
    {indexLine: 3, group: 9},
];

const groupedLines = Array.from(new Set(lines.map(x=>x.group))).map(y => lines.filter(z => z.group === y));

console.log(groupedLines);
```

Comment: Good  solution, how then to know  not array with associative keys but array of:

lines = [{"group": 4, "lines": []}]?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [lodash.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy)

`yarn add lodash.groupby` ( or `npm install lodash.groupby --save` )

```
import groupBy from 'lodash.groupby'; // 12.6k (gzipped 4.8k)

// ...

console.log(groupBy(this.lines, ({group}) => group)));
```

( self-explanatory code there, 0 WTFs per minute )